# Table last row does not fit bottom in IE 10

Tags: css, internet-explorer, row, css-tables

The code below link runs fine on Chrome, Firefox:

[link](http://jsfiddle.net/WLSq2/)

```
.enalt
{

display:table-row;
bottom:0;
position:absolute;

}
```

however the same code does not work properly in IE 10. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `height: 100%;` to the `tdiscell` class. `height: 100%` takes up 100% of the element's parent. So it won't be tall enough if the parent isn't tall enough.

Full CSS for the element

```
.tdiscell
{
    border:solid 2px #143357;
    display : table-cell;
    height: 100%; /* add this */
}
```